# Concat from Data Grid with Spoon

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have a problem using the javascript step transformation.

I have only three steps:

1- Data Grid (with the dataset)

Input:

```
Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3
   a      b      c
   d      e      f
```

2- Modified Java Script Value

```
var resultField = col1 + " " + col2 + " " + col3;
```

And resultField is the single Output field from the step

3- Text File Output

A simple csv where I need to export the result.

Expected Output 1 row with the result :

```
abcdef
```

Real Output 2 rows with splitted result:

```
abc
def
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share the complete code

Comment: Hi!, I have updated my question

Comment: So that's your code? `var resultField = col1 + " " + col2 + " " + col3;`? And with this we should now know/guess/understand what's wrong with your code? Try adding `\n` at the end of the string (`var resultField = col1 + " " + col2 + " " + col3 + '\n';`)

Comment: I'm not telling that my code is wrong, my problem is that I don't know how to do it. 
I know how to concatenate strings with javascript, but I don't know how to concatenate more than one row at once with kettle.

Answer (score 2):

Use your javascript (or calculator) to concatenate the columns on row 1, and then use the group by step to concatenate those multi-row results into one field.

So javascript gives you 2 rows:
abc
def

and after group by you get

abcdef

Whilst you can group across multiple rows in javascript, I wouldn't as it gets pretty messy.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly your problem, you want to concatenate all the rows from the data grid in the javascript step. The only way i think you can do that is by dumping the rows in a temporary file and loading that file in the javascript step.